# downloading an image with file_put_contents

Tags: php, apache, centos

I'm trying to download an image from an external site to a local folder but i'm getting the following error:

> file_put_contents(media/logos/7dbde54700af67e3703384c9599780ef):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

I've set ownership of the 'media/logos' folder to the 'apache' user by using the following commands:

```
chown -R apache:apache media/logos
chmod -R 777 media/logos
```

The ls -l command displays the following:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 3 apache apache     19 Jan 20 17:58 media
```

And my PHP code is as follows:

```
$ImageUrl = "http://www.example.com/media/image1.png";
$localPath = "media/logos/" . md5(uniqid());

file_put_contents($localPath, file_get_contents($ImageUrl));
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you noticed that the image you are saving has no extension (i.e. no .png)?  Do this `$localPath = "media/logos/" . md5(uniqid()) . '.png';` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use `copy()`

```
$ImageUrl = "http://www.example.com/media/image1.png";
$localPath = "media/logos/" . md5(uniqid());
copy($ImageUrl, $localPath);
```

now careful with your local path, I assume what you want really is

```
$localPath = __DIR__ . "/media/logos/" . md5(uniqid());
```

Comment: As above, add an extension as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately enough I'm still getting the same error after copying your code. Even after adding a PNG extension string in the $localPath variable.

    copy(/var/www/html/application/media/logos/20ec5a55adfba79866a2cea12245f27e.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Comment: php doesn't care about the extension, the issue here is that the path is relative to the current directory which is obviously not the directory that MC_nulty thinks it is, and cannot be know with only the code given in the question

Comment: what does `ls -l /var/www/html/application/media/logos` give you ?
also what does ls -l give you on each directory on the path (/var/www/html/application/media, /var/www/html/application, /var/www/html, /var/www) ? if any one of these directories is not readable you will get a permission denied